# How to detect for collisions with instantiated prefabs

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

I am making a first person shooter using bullets and I'm trying to find a way to delete the instances when it hits an enemy or the wall but its not working. The way I've done it is to give all the walls and enemy's a tag for specific collision detection but it doesn't seem to be working
for me.

plz help

```
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class BulletShoot : MonoBehaviour
{
    //bullet 
    public GameObject bullet;

    //bullet force
    public float shootForce, upwardForce;

    //Gun stats
    public float timeBetweenShooting, spread, reloadTime, timeBetweenShots;
    public int magazineSize, bulletsPerTap;
    public bool allowButtonHold;

    int bulletsLeft, bulletsShot;

    //Recoil
    public Rigidbody playerRb;
    public float recoilForce;

    //bools
    bool shooting, readyToShoot, reloading;

    //Reference
    public Camera fpsCam;
    public Transform attackPoint;

    //Graphics
    public GameObject muzzleFlash;
    public TextMeshProUGUI ammunitionDisplay;

    //bug fixing :D
    public bool allowInvoke = true;

    private void Awake()
    {
        //make sure magazine is full
        bulletsLeft = magazineSize;
        readyToShoot = true;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        MyInput();

        //Set ammo display, if it exists :D
        //if (ammunitionDisplay != null)
        //ammunitionDisplay.SetText(bulletsLeft / bulletsPerTap + " / " + magazineSize / bulletsPerTap);
    }

    private void MyInput()
    {
        //Check if allowed to hold down button and take corresponding input
        if (allowButtonHold) shooting = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse0);
        else shooting = Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0);

        //Reloading 
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R) && bulletsLeft < magazineSize && !reloading) Reload();
        //Reload automatically when trying to shoot without ammo
        if (readyToShoot && shooting && !reloading && bulletsLeft <= 0) Reload();

        //Shooting
        if (readyToShoot && shooting && !reloading && bulletsLeft > 0)
        {
            //Set bullets shot to 0
            bulletsShot = 0;

            Shoot();
        }
    }

    private void Shoot()
    {
        readyToShoot = false;

        //Find the exact hit position using a raycast
        Ray ray = fpsCam.ViewportPointToRay(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0)); //Just a ray through the middle of your current view
        RaycastHit hit;

        //check if ray hits something
        Vector3 targetPoint;
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            targetPoint = hit.point;
        else
            targetPoint = ray.GetPoint(75); //Just a point far away from the player

        //Calculate direction from attackPoint to targetPoint
        Vector3 directionWithoutSpread = targetPoint - attackPoint.position;

        //Calculate spread
        float x = Random.Range(-spread, spread);
        float y = Random.Range(-spread, spread);

        //Calculate new direction with spread
        Vector3 directionWithSpread = directionWithoutSpread + new Vector3(x, y, 0); //Just add spread to last direction

        //Instantiate bullet/projectile
        GameObject currentBullet = Instantiate(bullet, attackPoint.position, Quaternion.identity); //store instantiated bullet in currentBullet
        //Rotate bullet to shoot direction
        currentBullet.transform.forward = directionWithSpread.normalized;

        //Add forces to bullet
        currentBullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(directionWithSpread.normalized * shootForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
        currentBullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(fpsCam.transform.up * upwardForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
        if(currentBullet.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy"))
        {
            Destroy(currentBullet.gameObject, 3);
        }
        if (currentBullet.gameObject.CompareTag("Thing"))
        {
            Destroy(currentBullet.gameObject, 3);
        }


        //Instantiate muzzle flash, if you have one
        if (muzzleFlash != null)
            Instantiate(muzzleFlash, attackPoint.position, Quaternion.identity);

        bulletsLeft--;
        bulletsShot++;

        //Invoke resetShot function (if not already invoked), with your timeBetweenShooting
        if (allowInvoke)
        {
            Invoke("ResetShot", timeBetweenShooting);
            allowInvoke = false;
            

            //Add recoil to player (should only be called once)
            playerRb.AddForce(-directionWithSpread.normalized * recoilForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
        }

        //if more than one bulletsPerTap make sure to repeat shoot function
        if (bulletsShot < bulletsPerTap && bulletsLeft > 0)
            Invoke("Shoot", timeBetweenShots);
    }
    
    private void ResetShot()
    {
        //Allow shooting and invoking again
        readyToShoot = true;
        allowInvoke = true;
    }

    private void Reload()
    {
        reloading = true;
        Invoke("ReloadFinished", reloadTime); //Invoke ReloadFinished function with your reloadTime as delay
    }

    private void ReloadFinished()
    {
        //Fill magazine
        bulletsLeft = magazineSize;
        reloading = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two things to say.

The first is, it seems a little unnecessary to have a bullet object if you are using raycasting to find where you have hit, but it's alright if you want to do it like that.

The second is that the bullet object is not instant, so when you add forces to the bullet in Shoot(), the bullet still hasn't moved yet. You are then checking if it has collided with anything on the same frame, also in Shoot(), which still means the bullet hasn't moved yet. I would recommend moving the collision detection out of the Shoot() method and into a separate method that I would then call in update(), separately from Input().

Hope this helped :D